# How do I pass a file from parent to child package in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, parent-child, flatfilesource

Recently started working on SSIS package, I have two packages _main.dtsx & child.dtsx. the _main package contains foreach loop that parses through all the files in a specific folder on C: drive. Depending on the name of file I have added a constraint that only file which has word "accounts" will get picked up & should be passed to the child package that does the work of inserting the file data to database.

I have created a input package parameter in the child package as varFileName and added in the parameter binding on the main package where the Child's "Execute Package Task" is present in the loop container. The problem I'm facing now is how do I pass that parameter as an input source in the child's data flow task so that the data can be inserted into the database table.

As it is SSIS package there is not code & couldn't find the best way to explain the problem.

Comment: _ have created a input package parameter in the child package as varFileName _   _how do I pass that parameter as an input source in the child's data flow task_ Do you know how to use expressions? You should just be able to specify that the source path is an expression , and the expressio is `varFileName`

Comment: to add to @Nick.McDermaid's comment. Whenever the filename is variable, you should delay validation on the connection. There are exceptions, but that is pretty standard.